# How do I stabilize the pulse widths of the 4029 Binary Counter?

Tags: counter, binary, parasitic-capacitance

I am working with a [CD4029BE](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4029b.pdf?ts=1660552719752&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FCD4029B%252Fpart-details%252FCD4029BE%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Docb-tistore-promo-asc_opn_en-cpc-storeic-google-wwe%2526utm_content%253DDevice%2526ds_k%253DCD4029BE%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds%2526gclid%253DEAIaIQobChMI7N3B9LjI-QIVyZBoCR3uawoYEAAYASAAEgJcZvD_BwE) on a breadboard. The connections are as follows:

VDD to +12VDC
VSS to ground
The clock input receives a 3Hz 0 to +12V clock pulse
J1-J4 are shorted together, and then shorted to ground
Pin 5 (Carry in) to ground
Preset Enable shorted to ground
Up/Down and Binary/Decimal shorted to +12 to enable upward binary counting

The issue is that at the outputs, Q1-Q4, the outputs count correctly except that the pulse width randomly changes at all the outputs, meaning sometimes Q1 has a 50% duty cycle on/off, but every random number of pulses it will stay high or low for bit longer than it should; the same behavior happens at the other outputs.

I think this could be a stray capacitance issue, but the datasheet doesn't say anything about where bypass caps might be needed. If I add 0.1 or 0.001u ceramic caps near the power supply connections it affects the pulses at the outputs, but the outputs are still randomly different widths every so often.

I also tried a second 4029 IC that I had, and the same issue happens, but just with different random pulses wider or smaller on the outputs.

Please advise how I can stabilize the outputs of this IC.

Posted below is an image of my clock signal, which comes from the output of a 555 timer. The pulses' width is about 27-28 ms. Following that are detailed images of my clock rising edge (about 2us) and falling edge (0.4 us).

[image]
[image: Clock rising edge]
[image: Clock falling edge]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138578/discussion-on-question-by-thomas-wilk-how-do-i-stabilize-the-pulse-widths-of-the).